# Just want to show a green checkmark when user clicks Submit on html form

Tags: javascript, php, html

first post. PHP noob. I'm surprised at how difficult this has been...

I have an html form (index.html) with a submit button that posts to a php file (sendemail.php).

The php file is set to collect form data and send it via email to an address I specify.

I would like to display a success icon next to the submit button when this email is sent. (Honestly, there is no fail condition, so I would be happy with just displaying the success icon when the user clicks Submit, so they know not to keep clicking Submit).

I have tried a number of approaches after reading this and many other forums. I've been at this for two days and could use some help.

Here's some snippets below.  I'm basically just trying to detect the email being sent in the php file, then sending a flag ($val) using echo json_encode back to the HTML page. I'm trying to capture it using the javascript with an onload trigger, and then trying to use the javascript to manipulate the DIV visbility when the page is refreshed after the submit action is completed.

It processes the php but it doesn't seem to reach the Header line to reload the html page. It just refreshed the screen and shows the word "inline" and nothing else.

I'm stumped. Please help!  Thanks

sendmail.php

```
 // Check, if message sent to your email 
// mark success or fail then refresh page

if($send_contact){


$val="inline";   
echo json_encode($val); 

} 
else {
echo "Error"; 

}

if($send_contact){
header('location:index.html');

}
else {
echo "Error"; 
}
?>
```

javascript in html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function success(){
      var val = <?php echo json_encode($val); ?>;
       document.getElementById('success').setAttribute('display', val);

         }
       window.onload = success;
    </script>
```

HTML DIV I'm trying to control

```
 <div style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold; color:#000000; display:val;"

                class="success" id="success" name="success"><img src="success.png"

                  height="25px">Event added! It may take 20 minutes to appear on
                the calendar. </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok I tried manRo's suggestion and was able to get the behavior I wanted out of the green checkmark...it would be hidden on page load and then appear when it received the 200 status message from the PHP file.

However when I try to build this logic into my ajax something is breaking and the form data is no longer submitting, and the green checkmark logic stops working.

Allow me to run through my updates:

Currently my script header looks like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="util-functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="clear-default-text.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
```

I've got an onload in the body to call a function to set the green checkmark to "hidden", just to keep things tidy:

```
<body onload="setdisplay()">
```

Calling this function:

```
<script>
 function setdisplay();
  document.getElementById("success").style.display = "none";
</script>
```

I get my form started like this now:

```
 <form id="main" name="main" action="">
```

Here's an example input:

```
<td style="text-align: right; "> <br>
        </td>
        <td><input id="title" name="title" value="Event title" class="cleardefault rounded"

            required="true" type="text"> </td>
```

The form submit button, which currently is type=button

```
<input style="background-color: #99d6ff; text-align:center;
```

font-weight: bold;" value="Add event" id="addevent" name="addevent" onclick="processmain();"

```
           class="button" type="button">
```

This is the DIV I need to make visible or hidden depending on success:

```
 <div style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold; color:#000000; display:none;"

            class="success" id="success" name="success"><img src="success.png"

              height="25px"></div>
```

Now the beefy part....I've tried integrating your manRo's suggestions into my main form processing script, as part of the ajax "success" state:

```
     <script>
      }
      function processmain()
{



  // event.preventDefault();



      var title = $("input#title").val();
  var location = $("input#location").val();
  var startdate = $("input#startdate").val();
  var starttime = $("input#starttime").val();
  var enddate = $("input#enddate").val();
  var endtime = $("input#endtime").val();
  var other = $("input#other").val(); 


    $.ajax({



        url: "sendemail.php",
        type:'POST',
        data:
        {
          title: "title",
          location: "location",
          startdate: "startdate",
          starttime: "starttime",
          enddate: "enddate",
          endtime: "endtime",
          other: "other"
        },
        success: function(event)
        {
           $.get('sendmail.php', function(data) {
         document.getElementById("success").style.display = "inline";
           })               
        }    
    });}

    </script>
```

At the moment:
The form data is not passed to the php
The green checkmark does not show
The screen is no longer refreshing (because button type=button now, instead of submit).

I feel like I am close. I need to get the form data sent to the php so the email is sent. I need the page to not refresh so I can properly introduce the green checkmark.

Please take a look at how I'm implementing your solution in my code and let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!!

Comment: you can't send header after `echo json_encode($val);` please check http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is HTML form with ajax call to php script that will return 200 http status code on success.

I will try to explain you that on very simple example.

Please take a look at below html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="sendmail.php">
      <input type="email" name="email"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <script>
      $(document.forms[0]).submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get('sendmail.php', function(data) {
          alert('all good');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`sendmail.php` in that case should contain code responsible for sending email eg:

```
<?php
//code here...
if ($email_sent) {
    http_response_code(200);
} else {
    http_response_code(400);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe it is so simple! Was having trouble wrapping my mind around how Ajax is meant to pass data but this clears it up. Will go experiment now and follow up once I've got it. Thanks again! I'll upvote once I have enough rep!

Comment: Updated my approach based on your suggestions, but am running into new problems. Please see my update in the first post. Thanks!